# Coalesce statement to handle multiple values and NULLS?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, bi-publisher

I am trying to figure out how to create an SQL query that will check for (`:FROM_DATE`) and (`:TO_DATE`) parameters and if `NULL` to put the past month dates in for the two values, and if not `NULL` to accept whatever values are entered in the parameters.

For example:

- if the user enters (`01-JAN-17`) as `FROM_DATE`, and (`31-JAN-17`) as `TO_DATE`, I want the query to not automatically pass any values for the `TO_DATE` and `FROM_DATE`.
- if the user does not enter any values for `TO_DATE` and `FROM_DATE` or there are `NULL` values passed in, I want the query to automatically enter the the past months values (i.e., if query is run July 1st 2017, the `FROM_DATE` would be `01-JUN-17` and the `TO_DATE` would be `30-JUN-17`).

I was hinted to use a coalesce statement to handle multiple values and `NULLS` (i.e., `AND ( (coalesce(null, :P_ORG) is null) or (ORG.ORGANIZATION_ID in :P_ORG)))`???

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oracle and Postgresql have different functions for handling dates and times. Which one are you using ?

Comment: @cachique Sorry, its for Oracle BI Publisher....so Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE( :from_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                        AND     TO_DATE( :to_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
OR     (   ( :from_date IS NULL OR :to_date IS NULL )
       AND your_date_column BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
                            AND     TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - 1
       );
```

If either (or both) `:from_date` or `:to_date` is `NULL` then the dates will be compared to the previous month.

If your table has dates where the time component is not always set to midnight then you will need to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE( :from_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                        AND     TO_DATE( :to_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
OR     (   ( :from_date IS NULL OR :to_date IS NULL )
       AND your_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
       AND your_date_column <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
       );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you sir, it was exactly what I was looking for.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept: consider the following query, where we have dates and values, and we want to sum the values for the dates that fall between `:from_date` and `:to_date`. If either of them is `null`, the query will use the first day of the prior month for `from_date` and the last day of the prior month for `to_date`. Note that this will cause **problems** if one date is given an actual value and the other is left `null` - you didn't explain how you would want that handled. But that's a different issue.

I use SQL developer, and in it I don't know how to pass in dates; I show passing in strings, and converting them to dates.

```
with
     test_data ( dt, val ) as (
       select date '2017-05-29', 200 from dual union all
       select date '2017-06-13', 150 from dual union all
       select date '2017-06-18', 500 from dual
     )
select sum(val) as sum_val
from   test_data
where  dt between coalesce(to_date(:from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
                                                   add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1))
              and coalesce(to_date(:to_date  , 'yyyy-mm-dd'), trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1)
;
```

Comment: You have the `:to_date` at the start of the `BETWEEN` range and `:from_date` at the end and it won't use the previous month as the range if exactly one of the bind variable is `NULL` - it will use a combination of the non-`NULL` value and the previous month.

Comment: @MT0 - Thanks for catching the to/from confusion, I had it in the post also and fixed it but not in the code. I mentioned explicitly the issue with only one of the inputs being NULL; the OP did not state what the desired behavior is in that case. I just made a different guess than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `COALESCE` (or Oracle's `NVL`). When a parameter is null, replace it with the default date.

```
select *
from mytable
where mydate >= coalesce(:from_date, trunc(sysdate - interval '1' month), 'month')
  and mydate <= coalesce(:to_date, last_day(sysdate - interval '1' month));
```